# How to get AccessToken and also close browser window in ReadyAPI

Tags: groovy, access-token, ready-api, oltu

I wrote some code that gets an access token.  When the code runs, a browser displays on the screen which contains the access token.

But when I try to get the access token and log it, a null string is being displayed.   Also, I do not know if there is a way to force the browser to close using my code.  Right now when I run this code, the browser window opens but I have to click on it to close it.

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong ?

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.actions.oauth.OltuOAuth2ClientFacade
import com.eviware.soapui.support.editor.inspectors.auth.TokenType

def project = context.getTestCase().getTestSuite().getProject();
def oAuthProfile = project.getAuthRepository().getEntry("IMAGEN_Profile");
def clientSecret = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("Client_Secret")
def clientID = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("Client_ID")
oAuthProfile.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
oAuthProfile.setClientID(clientID);
log.info("Client Secret:"+clientSecret)
log.info("Client ID:"+clientID)

// the following code for getting new access token
def oAuthClientFacade = new OltuOAuth2ClientFacade(TokenType.ACCESS);
oAuthClientFacade.requestAccessToken(oAuthProfile, true);
def accessToken = oAuthProfile.getAccessToken()
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("Auth_Code",accessToken)
log.info("Access Token:"+accessToken)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the SoapUI documentation is rather *terse*.

Change your

```
oAuthClientFacade.requestAccessToken(oAuthProfile, true);
```

to

```
oAuthClientFacade.requestAccessToken(oAuthProfile, true, true);
```

[source](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/projects/requests/auth/types/oauth2/automate/sample.html#calling-the-automated-retrieval-procedure)

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. I am not getting the access token.  it says null.  Is your  script  in a event handler and how it was set up.

Comment: @MyDisplayName I followed the instructions at that link almost exactly, including setting things up as an event handler, and it works fine for me!

Comment: @Siking : I tried the same script in CI/CD pipeline and it is failing. could you please help